# GPT (Google Publisher Tag) - Detect if disable initial load already invoked

Tags: google-tag-manager, publisher, google-publisher-tag

Is this possible to detect if [disableInitialLoad()](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.PubAdsService_disableInitialLoad) was already invoked on the page?

Answer (score 1):

There's an [API method](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.PubAdsService_isInitialLoadDisabled) you can use:

```
// The following is true if disableInitialLoad() was called
googletag.pubads().isInitialLoadDisabled()
```

You can use this to detect whether or not you need to run `googletag.pubads().refresh()`, for instance.